# SQL Server results vary using COALESCE and OR

Tags: sql-server-2008

The below queries are generating different counts. it seems to me they are identical.

```
SELECT 
    COUNT(*)
FROM 
    item1 
RIGHT JOIN 
    (Item2 
INNER JOIN 
    item_master ON Item2.Number = item_master.number) AND (item1.itemId = Item2.itemId)
WHERE  
    COALESCE([Item2].[Amount], item1.Amount, [item_master].[amount], 0 ) > 0

SELECT 
    COUNT(*)
FROM 
    item1 
RIGHT JOIN 
    (Item2 
INNER JOIN 
    item_master ON Item2.Number = item_master.number) AND (item1.itemId = Item2.itemId)
WHERE  
    (Item2.Amount is not NULL and Item2.Amount > 0) OR
    (item1.Amount is not NULL and item1.Amount > 0) OR 
    (item_master.amount is not NULL and item_master.amount > 0)
```

Comment: The extra `, 0` parameter in `COALESCE` is unnecessary and -in my opinion- confusing.

Comment: But isn't NULL > 0 an issue?

Comment: That results in false, as will `0 > 0`. :) You also don't need the `Item2.Amount is not NULL` and similar checks in the second query.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

they're different. `COALESCE([Item2].[Amount], item1.Amount, [item_master].[amount], 0 ) > 0` is true if the first non-null value of the three is greater than 0.

Second condition is true if there is any non-null value greater than 0.

Comment: but isnt that the same when evaluated ?

Comment: No. If Item2.Amount would be 0 and item1.Amount would be 1, then COALESCE would still return 0 and the whole expression (0 > 0) would be false, regardless of the `1` in item1.Amount. In plain English the difference is between "First non-null" and "Any", which have quite a different meaning.

Answer (score 0):

here's why they're different: coalesce is only going to evaluate against the first non-null value. the 2nd query will accept any of the 3 inputs for evaluation.

take for example the values [-1, 5, null]

- the 1st query: evaluates to false because -1 <= 0.
- the 2nd query: the 5 > 0 so it evaluates to true.

if you want to use coalesce in the first query, you'd want to do something like this:

```
where (coalesce(item2.amount, 0) > 0
or coalesce(item1.amount, 0) > 0
or coalesce(item_master.amount, 0) > 0)
```